# Pretty print Python dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary, printing, pretty-print

I'm used to use the `pprint` module to pretty print my built-in Python container objects such as `dict` and `list`. However when printing, I'm faced with the difficulty of forcing the containers to use the `__str__` on the contained objects (since by default they use the `__repr__` method on the contained objects), whilst maintaining the pretty printing.

Here is an example:

```
import pprint

class H:
    """ Example of a contained object
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return "This is my H class string representation"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "H()"

d = {
    'a': H(),
    'b': {
        'c': H(),
        'd': H()
    }
}

pprint.pprint(d, width=10)
```

returns d pretty printed:

```
{'a': H(),
 'b': {'c': H(),
       'd': H()}}
```

But as you can see the `__repr__` is called on the H objects.

To force the dict to use the `__str__` on the contained objects, some people suggested using `join()`. Something like:

```
print("{" + "\n".join("{!r}: {!s},".format(k, v) for k, v in d.items()) + "}")
```

which returns:

```
{'a': This is my H class string representation,
'b': {'c': H(), 'd': H()},}
```

And obviously won't work on nested dictionaries, and also there's no way to use `pprint` in that case since after the join we end up with a string.

Ideally what I would like to have printed is:

```
{'a': This is my H class string representation,
 'b': {'c': This is my H class string representation,
       'd': This is my H class string representation}}
```

For context, the keys of my dictionaries are always strings, and the values are the objects in question such as `H()`, of whom I need the `__str__` represenation and not the `__repr__`.

Comment: Could you make `__repr__` return `self.__str__()`? if yes, it works as you expected

Comment: "I'm faced with the difficulty of forcing the containers to use the `__str__` on the contained objects" - there's a very good reason `pprint` doesn't do that. When `__str__` differs from `__repr__`, the `__str__` output is typically not designed to be clearly delimited from surrounding text, or to be distinguishable from the `__str__` output of unrelated types. You're likely to cause yourself a lot of confusion with what you're trying.

Comment: Look how you've unconsciously used the `repr` output instead of the `str` output for the keys of your dicts. Imagine if `pprint` used `str`, and one of your keys was `'1: 2'`. Or imagine if you had an exception in your dict, since the `str` output of an exception is the same as the `str` of its argument (or tuple of arguments).

Comment: I do understand the good reason behind containers using `__repr__`, to avoid ambuiguity. However in this particular case I am aware of what each of my objects is and how they behave. My program involves parsing the string output of these dictionaries, so I need their string representation. And I want to keep the `__repr__` as is to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: [pprint source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/pprint.py) is not very large. Why not just modify it to get a module (call it e.g. `pprint2`) which suits your needs?

Comment: I haven't thought of that, I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python allow to dynamically change methods in classes. So you could just temporarily have `__repr__` be `__str__`:

```
def str_pprint(d):
    sv = H.__repr__
    H.__repr__ = H.__str__
    pprint.pprint(d, width=10)
    H.__repr__ = sv

str_pprint(d)
```

With your data, it gives as expected:

```
{'a': This is my H class string representation,
 'b': {'c': This is my H class string representation,
       'd': This is my H class string representation}}
```

But **beware**: this changes globally the class attributes, so this cannot be used if multiple execution threads (multithreaded programs or interuption handlers) are expected.

Comment: This is thread-unsafe (and unsafe in the presence of same-thread interruptions like `__del__` methods).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: I mainly use Python for simple linear scripts so I did not even think to warn about it. Now done, and thank for commenting...

Comment: Yes I agree that this is very thread-unsafe. However I will mark this as accepted since you've put in the warning. Meanwhile I will look into the pprint module to see if I can tweak to my purpose here. Thank you all for answering.